# JIRA : Why can we only bulk 1000 tickets by default?

Tags: jira, bulk

This limit has caused me much more time. What is the reason behind this setting that is so sophisticated that I can't even find on the internet ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Bulk editing in Jira is a **memory intensive operation**. Jira has this intentional limit to avoid performance degradation or even `OutOfMemoryException`, which could cause your instance to crash.

You can override this limit **AT YOUR OWN RISK**, by configuring your own [jira-config.properties](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/advanced-jira-configuration-126006.html) and add the following override properties. An example to set the limit to 2000:

```
jira.bulk.edit.limit.issue.count=2000
```

Comment: Thank you @bertperrisor. Why is it a memory intensive operation? Because I've seen much bigger data operations in other software within a click of mouse/line of command. The data volume of a ticket in JIRA should be fairly small since it is mostly text based multi-lined data. Maybe it's bad analogy but I didn't any such limits in SQL or Excel.

Comment: I'm not sure why I've missed your comment. Anyway, Jira is a Java app. I'm guessing it could be how the code lies beneath that a chunk of the heap is pulled for the bulk editing process.

Comment: Just to add to this explanation: The data of a Jira issue is not stored in a single row in a database table, but is depending on which custom field is mapped to the issue type for a certain project by which schemes etc. So it's a lot of operations which make bulk operations also very CPU intensive. But it of course still depends if you have 50 users w/o any performance issues or 50k users with daily performance degradation on our Jira instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to change the jira.bulk.edit.limit.issue.count parameter.
Here is how I would approach the problem.

I had like 3000 issues to bulk change, custom field was empty and I need to add the same value to that custom field.

In the JQL filter add at the end: AND "MyCustomField" is EMPTY

(MyCustomField can be any of your custom field that you want to bulk change.)

It will list all issues where that custom field is empty, in my case 3000 issues.

Now I go to: Tools > maximum 1,000 issues
Then edit those 1000 issues out of 3000 total.

Then you run the same JQL search again and will have 2000 issues with that custom field left empty.

Do the same again: Tools > maximum 1,000 issues
Then edit those 1000 issues out of 2000 total.

Than again the same, until you have no more issues with that custom field left empty.

Comment: Please use syntaxhighlight so it gets more readable :-)